# What is the EOL (End of Life) for Rails 2.3?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-2, end-of-life

What is the EOL date for Rails 2.3?

Answer (score 9):

2.3 reached EOL on 2013-06-25, when rails 4.0.0 was released.

Only the "last major release series" will receive patches, according to [Michael Koziarski](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/rubyonrails-security/G4TTUDDYbNA).  Therefore, when 4.0 was released, 2.3 stopped receiving patches.

The rails team had hoped to drop support for 2.3 much earlier.  On 2011-12-29 [Aaron said](https://github.com/rails/rails/pull/4202#issuecomment-3302010):

> .. we have no plans of releasing another version of 2.3 [beyond 2.3.14]

Before that, on 2011-06-08, [Aaron said](http://weblog.rubyonrails.org/2011/6/8/ann-rails-2-3-12-has-been-released/):

> This branch [2.3] is in security-maintenance mode. We will release it when there are problems like "the sky is falling", or major security issues. It's time for us to focus on pushing Rails forward!

Comment: On a related note, `ruby 1.8.7` reaches EOL this month (June 2013).  "We will no longer support 1.8.7 in all senses after June 2013." - [Urabe Shyouhei](http://www.ruby-lang.org/en/news/2011/10/06/plans-for-1-8-7/)

Comment: As of a few years ago, rails now has an [official maintenance policy](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/maintenance_policy.html)

Answer (score 1):

There is a [commercial service](http://railslts.com) that will continue to provide security patches for Rails 2.3 after the version has reached EOL (when Rails 4 is released).

Comment: This is useful information, but technically (quite pedantically) not an answer to the OP's question. :)

Comment: Yes, and the link to RailsLTS should be a *comment*, not an answer.