# How to Override views,controllers,stylesheets, and javascripts for whole application through rails plugin

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-plugins

I need to override controllers,views and js through plugin in rails 2.3
My client has some application which i do not need to modify.
If any feature require i need to implement through *plugin* only.
Can any one help me how to implement this thing.
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

There is quite a bit information available when searching for rails plugins or engines.  The options to extend a rails application was [improved considerably in rails 3](http://railscasts.com/episodes/277-mountable-engines?view=asciicast).  Since your client is running rails 2, a good place to start is the [Rails 2 plugin documentation](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/v2.3.8/plugins.html) or the [rails 2.3 engine railscast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/149-rails-engines?view=asciicast).  Note that rails 2 [has reached end of life](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10134109/what-is-the-eol-end-of-life-for-rails-2-3).

Regards

Comment: thanks for responding.Actually i want to replace content of view(particular one). and as well as want to add custom stylesheet (whole application) into the head tag.How can i do this thing.

Comment: And also i am new to ruby on rails please help me to solve this problem.